# How to replace letters in a string with a hash value

Tags: ruby

I want to extract some letters from a word and replace the letters by their chemical symbol.

This works, but it's TOOOO long. I am sure there is a way to make it shorter:

```
puts "Enter your name"
name = gets.chomp

if name.include? 'br'
  name.gsub!('br', 'Br')
end
if name.include? 'ba'
  name.gsub!('ba', 'Ba')
end
if name.include? 'cr'
  name.gsub!('cr', 'Cr')
end

if name.include? 'ac'
  name.gsub!('ac', 'Ac')
end

if name.include? 'al'
  name.gsub!('al', 'Al')
end

if name.include? 'am'
  name.gsub!('am', 'Am')
end
```

I am trying to do this way but it doesn't work. What is wrong?

```
puts "Enter your name"
name = gets.chomp

     symbols = {
     :ac => "Ac",
     :al => "Al",
     :am => "Am",
     :br => "Br",
     :ba => "Ba",
     :cr => "Cr"
    }


if name.include? symbols
  symbols.each{ |key, value| name.gsub!(key, value) }
end

puts name
```

I get the following error:

```
breakingbad.rb:15:in `include?': no implicit conversion of Hash into String (TypeError)
        from breakingbad.rb:15:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use String as Hash key. [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-gsub) also accepts a Hash as second argument.

> If the second argument is a Hash, and the matched text is one of its
>   keys, the corresponding value is the replacement string.

```
symbols = {
  'ac' => "Ac",
  'al' => "Al",
  'am' => "Al",
  'br' => "Br",
  'ba' => "Ba",
  'cr' => "Cr"
}
puts "Enter your name"
name = gets.chomp
name.gsub!(/#{symbols.keys.join('|')}/, symbols)
puts name
```

Comment: that works perfectly but  I don't really understand this line `name.gsub!(/#{symbols.keys.join('|')}/, symbols)`
can you explain it a bit please?

Comment: That is a regex, equivalent to `/(ac|al|am|br|ba|cr)/`. Your code should also work if you call `to_s` on the symbol. `symbols.each{ |key, value| name.gsub!(key.to_s, value) }`. Also `if name.include? symbols` is wrong. include method expects a String argument.

Comment: Tiny fix needed: `'am' => "Am",`

Comment: You'd be much better off with `Regexp.union(symbols.keys)` so that you don't have to make assumptions about the contents of the `symbol.keys` strings.